# ¿Como saber el numero de registro en una consulta multigrupo MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo una tabla en MYSQL la cual tiene una columna que se llama 'GrupoGradoAño' la cual identifica el Nivel de un alumno en la institución, Me gustaría saber si se puede generar una consulta la cual me diga cuantos registros hay por cada nivel sin tener que hacer múltiples consultas!

Ejemplo

```
'ID'|'GrupoGradoAño' 
  1 |    1° Año
  2 |    1° Año
  3 |    2° Año
  4 |    2° Año
  5 |    2° Año
```

Quiero que la consulta me devuelva que en '1° Año' hay 2 registros y a su vez que en '2° Año' hay 3 registros! Es posible eso en una única consulta?

Comment: Hola David, te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a group by y count(). Con esas dos clausulas podrás sacar los resultados que esperas. Si tras haberlo intentado tienes dudas, edita tu pregunta con la consulta que has intentado y te ayudaremos en lo que podamos.

Comment: Muchas gracias me a funcionado!

Comment: Me alegro David, te recomendaría que te contestases a tu misma pregunta con lo que has hecho para que si en un futuro alguien tiene la misma duda, pueda ver como lo solucionaste. O si en el caso de que la respuesta de @Aprendiz haya solucionado tu problema la podrías marcar como "Respuesta aceptada".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comento que tu consulta debería verse de este modo:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids, COUNT(GrupoGradoAnio) AS PorAnio
FROM demo
GROUP BY GrupoGradoAnio;
```

¿Por qué?

- Todos los `id` de cada renglón son únicos, entonces no podemos hacer un `GROUP BY(id)` por que nos devolvería algo como esto:

Resultado

```
id  PorAnio
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
```

- Como cada `id` es único por renglón entonces necesitamos agrupar múltiples de ellos por cada fila donde coincidan por el `GrupoGradoAño` y agrupar
- Para lograr la agrupación anterior la podemos aplicar como:

Agrupación múltiple

```
GROUP_CONCAT(columna)
```

- Hacemos uso de la función `COUNT()` que cuenta y reduce a un solo renglón de resultados por coincidencia, de este modo:

Comando

```
COUNT(GrupoGradoAnio)
```

- Finalmente como la función anterior, agrupa y reduce a un solo renglón, necesitamos agrupar por cada coincidencia, de este modo:

Comando

```
GROUP BY GrupoGradoAnio
```

Resultado obtenido:

```
ids   PorAnio
1,2     2
3,4,5   3
```